why does moving a textbox move an associated form label in Microsoft Access?
After removing the layout for textboxes in a form, was able to move them side by side, as:
form
However, trying to bring the two textboxes together just moves the label about.  Why is this?  The layout has been removed.
Looking to move the textboxes only without causing any changes to the labels.  Specifically to move "title" closer to "name" and preferably applying a layout to the other labels and textboxes.
